# How to create a Base Dialog?

Tags: android

I am trying to create a BaseDialog and re use it all over application. But I am facing a issue on this. My BaseDialog class is

```
public class BaseDialog extends Dialog {

    private Context mContext;

    public BaseDialog(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
    }

    public BaseDialog(@NonNull Context context, int themeResId) {
        super(context, themeResId);
        mContext = context;
    }

    protected BaseDialog(@NonNull Context context, boolean cancelable, @Nullable DialogInterface.OnCancelListener cancelListener) {
        super(context, cancelable, cancelListener);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        /**
         * My Common code here for all alert
         */
        super.show();
    }
}
```

And I am using this class as following is working fine.

```
public class ConfirmCancelDialog extends BaseDialog{
    public ConfirmCancelDialog(Context context, boolean cancelable,
                               OnCancelListener cancelListener) {
        super(context, cancelable, cancelListener);
    }

    public ConfirmCancelDialog(Context context, int theme) {
        super(context, theme);
    }

    public ConfirmCancelDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.confirm_cancel_dialog);

        //My remaining code
    }
}
```

But If if I try like following code I am getting error.

```
private void showDialog(){
        BaseDialog passwordDialog = new BaseDialog(context);
        passwordDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        passwordDialog.setContentView(R.layout.password);
        //Rest of my code
    }
```

I am getting error in `setContentView();`

But If I use  `Dialog passwordDialog = new Dialog(context);`my code is working fine. I want to use my BaseDialog in my entire application. Can any one help on me this Please?

I am getting the following error:

```
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:812)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:752)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:883)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:846)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:522)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:430)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:412)
        at android.app.Dialog.setContentView(Dialog.java:519)
        at sonosite.com.dialogwithsound.BaseDialog.<init>(BaseDialog.java:50)
        at sonosite.com.dialogwithsound.MainActivity.showPasswordPromptDialog(MainActivity.java:219)
        at sonosite.com.dialogwithsound.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:61)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5647)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22465)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6238)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/sonosite.com.dialogwithsound-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:367)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:112)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:77)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:359)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeElements(DexPathList.java:323)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:263)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:126)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:48)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
2019-02-14 16:14:11.795 30451-30451/sonosite.com.dialogwithsound E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.PathClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(PathClassLoaderFactory.java:43)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:58)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:522)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:555)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.getTopLevelResources(ActivityThread.java:1924)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:768)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.<init>(ContextImpl.java:2077)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2022)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5394)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
```

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: How about you use LayoutInflater? `LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context); View reportDialog = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_report_popup, null); setView(reportDialog);` and move it inside the constructor

Comment: passwordDialog.setContentView(R.layout.password); set the password dlaog.show to open the dialog and used to on create inflate the layout.